# Recovering (own) resource that has been deleted by community bot

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions, community-bot

In the case of the deletion of a resource (a question in my case) by the "community bot" - whatever *this* is - I simply want to know if it's possible to either:

1. know the reason why it has been deleted? / know the mechanism that conducted the bot to delete it? I'm curious.
2. be able to get the source code of that question (I'm currently unable to figure out a way to fetch it back - it's weird because *I* did write it) so that I may eventually ask it elsewhere if truly inappropriate here?

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at [the community user deleted my question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) which is linked from the deleted by message.

Assuming you are asking about [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473340/qgis-3-28-reports-a-postgresql-erroneous-query-select-pg-get-serial-sequence) it seems to fall under the first option:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has no active bounty

Answer (score 1):

The automated deletion process is described at [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/215590).

To determine how it applied to your question would need that question to be identified.

As [commented by @Mayken](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/recovering-own-resource-that-has-been-deleted-by-community-bot#comment11407_5458):

> You can find links to your deleted posts from your "[deleted questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)" and your "[deleted answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current)" pages. Links to the above deleted post pages can be found at the bottom of the respective [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions) and [answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) tabs in your profile.

Comment: Well, with this I realized I answered many questions that were deleted after the question was closed and nobody scored points. Generally, I answer new users' questions, who don't know how to format a clear question and that ends in a low rate of accepted answers (the user gets the job done without knowing how this site works and doesn't close the topic, some of them leave a greeting message but the don't accept the answer). This makes me rethink my activity here since a lot of the work I invested in formulating the answers vanished and is no longer available for further users

Comment: @aldo_tapia I think it’s always best to improve unclear questions before embarking on trying to answer them but it’s never too late to resurrect an answer you invested effort in writing by editing to clarify the question then flagging for undeletion of the Q&A.